# Using Kimono api data in php

Tags: php, json, api

I am a noob in api so please bear with me. I tried google searching for 1 hour but I can't understand anything from the results.

Currently, I have an API in kimono with the given example data :

```
{
  "name": "Summoners-Details",
  "count": 31,
  "frequency": "On demand",
  "version": 7,
  "newdata": false,
  "lastrunstatus": "success",
  "thisversionrun": "Tue Sep 02 2014 02:34:07 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "lastsuccess": "Tue Sep 02 2014 02:34:07 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "stats": {
    "retriedUrls": [],
    "failedUrls": [],
    "successful": 1,
    "rows": 31,
    "retried": 0,
    "failed": 0,
    "duration": 1894
  },
  "results": {
    "rank": [
      {
        "division": "Wukong's Lancers Silver-tier II"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the php code I am trying to use to get the division data, but I am getting nothing!  :

```
<?php
$request = "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/c6qj1oc?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$results = json_decode($response, TRUE);

$division = $results->{'results'}->{'rank'}->{'division'};
echo $division;
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

1. Remove the "true" parameter from `json_decode()`
2. Add `[0]` after `{'rank'}`.

---

Your problem is with how you are using `json_decode()`... the second parameter (true) is telling it to return an associative array rather than an object.

Secondly, the `rank` section of that JSON is an array, so you'll need to use the zero key to access its values.

Array access would be like this:

```
$division = $results['results']['rank'][0]['division'];
```

Otherwise, remove the true parameter and it will default to an object, and you'd access that variable like this:

```
$division = $results->results->rank[0]->division;
```

Here's some more info on [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Keep in mind that technically the `$division` definition you've already got would work fine (adding the zero array key) with an object instead of an array, I've only removed the `{'xxx'}` brackets because they are unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! :D I actually edited to api to get more data in array format so I guess the true notation is present. Your explanation on array access solved my problem! cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to scrowler's explanation, I have been able to get my data to show up. Here's the working code:

```
<?php
$request = "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/c6qj1oc?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$results = json_decode($response, TRUE);

$division = $results['results']['rank'];

foreach($division as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value['division'];
}
?>
```

Not really sure if the foreach loop is really needed but hey, might be usefull in the future :D

Comment: NB: the foreach is not necessary, it's just a way of accessing the rank array without needing a numeric index. As for whether it might be useful in the future - it would if you anticipate the possibility of multiple ranks being returned, which by all means might be plausible since Kimono have decided to return it as an array to start with. Up to you how you'd deal with multiple values coming back though.